# FedEx: Authentication Failed with test account

Tags: soap, wsdl, fedex

I'm trying to integrate FedEx with my application. I created a test account.
When I send RateRequest I got a response Authentication Failed (code is 1000).
I use v10 of Fedex Rate service. For SOAP I use Savon ruby gem.

Here is code I use:

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

TEST_URL = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate'

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = File.expand_path("../rate_wsdl.xml", __FILE__)
  wsdl.endpoint = TEST_URL
end

client.request "RateRequest" do
  soap.body = {
    'WebAuthenticationDetail' => {'Key' => KEY, 'Password' => PASSWORD},
    'ClientDetail' => {'AccountNumber' => ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 'MeterNumber' => METER_NUMBER},
    'RequestedShipment' => {
      'PackagingType' => 'FODEX_BOX',
      'Shipper' => 
        {'Address' => {'PostalCode' => '90210', 'CountryCode' => 'US', 'Residential' => 'true'}
      },
      'Recipient' => 
        {'Address' => {'PostalCode' => 'KIP 1J1', 'CountryCode' => 'CA', 'Residential' => 'true'}
      },
      'RateRequestTypes' => 'ACCOUNT',
      'PackageCount' => '1',
      'RequestedPackages' => {
        'Weight' => {'Units' => 'LB', 'Value' => '7.5'},
        'Dimensions' => {'Length' => '15', 'Width' => '10', 'Height' => '5', 'Units' => 'IN'}
      }
      #'LabelSpecification' => ''
    }
  }
end
```

I googled a lot about it. Some people had the same problem. People say it can be caused because of lack of permission of address validation, but I can't find how I can disable it if so.
I am sure that all credentials are OK (account number, meter number, key, password).
Also I tried "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-service" for endpoint url as well.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out of was wrong. I sent invalid SOAP request. Thanks to SOAPUI tool, it helped me to validate my request.

Comment: ,, I am facing the same issue now.i tried with following url in wsdl file "gateway.fedex.com/web-services"; , "gatewaybeta.fedex.com/web-services";. I am using RateService_v10.wsdl file. Still i am getting the error. Kindly advice on this